# How to preserve a 'complete' event across two RxJS observables?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable `const numbers = from([1,2,3])` which will emit 1, 2, 3, then complete.

I need to map this to another observable e.g. like this:

```
const mapped = numbers.pipe(
   concatMap(number => Observable.create(observer => {
     observer.next(number);
   }))
 );
```

But now the resulting observable `mapped` emits 1, 2, 3 but not the complete event.

How can I preserve the complete event in `mapped`?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619428/6680611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives me just "`1`" (with RxJS 6); are you sure you see 3 values?

```js
Rx.from([1,2,3]).pipe(
   op.concatMap(number => Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
     observer.next(number);
   }))
 ).forEach(x => console.log(x)).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

You're never completing the created Observable (it emits one value but never calls `observer.complete()`).  This works:

```js
Rx.from([1,2,3]).pipe(
   op.concatMap(number => Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
     observer.next(number); observer.complete();
   }))
 ).forEach(x => console.log(x)).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

This all shows how *hard* it is to use `Rx.Observable.create()` correctly.  The point of using Rx is to write your code using higher-level abstractions.  A large part of this is preferring to use operators in preference to observers.  E.g. in your case (which is admittedly simple):

```js
Rx.from([1,2,3])
  .pipe(op.concatMap(number => Rx.of(number)))
  .forEach(x => console.log(x)).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Comment: You're right. I made that example using `Observable.create` to replace the complex situation I was working with but didn't bother to check it. I'm having a look my original situation to see if I can find out what was happening

Comment: I think that the problem may have been that originally my `concatMap` returned an observable that would sometimes never emit anything (with `observer.next`)